# Find max of the 2nd element in a tuple - Python

Tags: python, find, tuples, max

Given a tuple list, i can find the max of the 1st element in the tuple list by:

```
>>> a,b,c,d = (4,"foo"),(9,"bar"),(241,"foobar"), (1,"barfoo")
>>> print max([a,b,c,d])
(241,"foobar")
```

But how about finding the max of the 2nd element? and how about the max of a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter:

```
import operator

max([a, b, c, d], key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

The `max()` of a string is based on the byte values of the string; `'a'` is higher than `'A'` because `ord('a')` is higher than `ord('A')`.

For your example input, `(241,"foobar")` is still the max value, because `'f'` > `'b'` and `'foobar'` is longer (more values) than `'foo'`, and `'b'` > `''` (with `b` being the character following the letters `foo` in the longer string).

Answer (score 3):

Even shorter is to use a lambda as the callable

```
max([a, b, c, d], key=lambda t: t[1])
```